# Making REST Template call and Web Client calls in the same Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers, webclient, resttemplate

I have a Spring boot application wherein I am making call to one external api using Web Client, and a call to another api using RestTemplate. Is it possible that the Headers set in the Rest Template instance are being used in Web Client instance as well. My RestTemplate call is working but my WebClient call is failing, it is giving incorrect parameters, probably because of headers. Can somebody please help

Comment: Please post some code snippet or error message to describe what problem you meet.

Answer (score -1):

You can call the API using the headers which is coming as part of the web app request:

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@POST
@Path(REQUEST_API)
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON_CHARSET_UTF_8)
public Response apiCall(
@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
     Map<String, List<String>> headers = httpHeaders.getRequestHeaders();
     restTemplate.exchange("EXTERNAL_API_TO_CALL", httpMethod, requestEntity, 
                           responseType);

}
```